# How to check url is reachable or not

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to check server url is reachable or not in android.
url which i want to check is like this: `https://mydomain.se:8081/` and also reachable from internet. But getting a problem as sometime below method return true and some time false.

```
  public boolean isBackendAccessAble(String serverUrl) {
    String host = serverUrl.substring(serverUrl.indexOf("://") + 3, serverUrl.lastIndexOf(":"));
    int port = Integer.parseInt(serverUrl.substring(serverUrl.lastIndexOf(":") + 1, serverUrl.length() - 1));
    boolean isReachable = false;
    try {
        SocketAddress sockAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        Socket sock = new Socket();
        int timeoutMs = 2000; // 2 seconds
        sock.connect(sockAddress, timeoutMs);
        isReachable = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to check serverUrl:" +   serverUrl);
    }
    return isReachable;
}
```

is there any other alternative to check the server from android over mobile data?

Comment: Yes offcourse mobile have. even i can browse the backend url from phone browser.

Comment: So, your methond returns true or false even with internet connection ?

Comment: Yes. sometime it return me true and some time return false.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805580/how-to-quickly-check-if-url-server-is-available

Answer (score -2):

```
 public boolean isBackendAccessAble(String serverUrl) {
    String host = serverUrl.substring(serverUrl.indexOf("://") + 3, serverUrl.lastIndexOf(":"));
    int port = Integer.parseInt(serverUrl.substring(serverUrl.lastIndexOf(":") + 1, serverUrl.length() - 1));
    boolean isReachable = false;
    try {
        SocketAddress sockAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        Socket sock = new Socket();
        int timeoutMs = 2000; // 2 seconds
        sock.connect(sockAddress, timeoutMs);
        isReachable = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to check serverUrl:" +   serverUrl);
 if (e instanceof SocketTimeoutException ){
   //the url is not reachable
isReachable=false;
 }
    }
    return isReachable;
}
```

Comment: i find a problem. this is because of calling this method from a main thread so it is given me exception sometime: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. Can someone give me hint if i use new thread and use this connection stuff with run, how i can add wait until started thread finish and give response back ?