# I need to check synchronously if an url of server is working, it returns false everytime error: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android, url, inetaddress

When I want to reach a server, url or website, my function returns false everytime.
I want a function that indicates me the code status 200, the function must wait I think to give me a true or a false... I don't want async solutions.

```
 private boolean isServerReachable() {
        try {
            InetAddress.getByName("http://www.google.com").isReachable(2000); 
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas ?
I based my code on that ticket that is popular:  [Ticket 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805580/how-to-quickly-check-if-url-server-is-available)
Thanks in advance

Comment: @jeprubio this ticket is very popular and talks about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285860/how-can-i-programmatically-test-an-http-connection

Comment: _"Any ideas ?"_ Yes, search for "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" and you'll understand the problem. There's a way to disable the [StrictMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode) that prevents network on main thread however. On the other hand you can make it "kind of synchoronous" with Java's [Future](https://www.baeldung.com/java-future) for example if you wait for `isDone()` to return true and use a Thread inside the Future. But is it a good solution, really?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen thank you. But why this ticket is so popular if this doesn't work ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285860/how-can-i-programmatically-test-an-http-connection

Comment: @jeprubio this ticket very very very popular does it, for android, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570292/3581620

Comment: @jeprubio In my question, I put the google.com site. I have an error for this. No logical

Answer (score -1):

You can change `"http://www.google.com"` to `google.com` this parameter is `host name`.

Comment: How does this solve the problem?